# knockout.js update property of bound array items on select change

Tags: knockout.js

I have a select which I want to bind to an observable array. I want to set the title attribute of the option for each item bound to a observable boolean in the model items. And if the section changes I want to set the value for that boolean for eachitem in the observable array to false and then set the one for the newley selected item to true.

My question is how to go about this:
- Is it possible to set the title attribute of the option elements as generated by the options binding?
- Is it possible to set a boolean of the bound item instead of a seperate property using the value binding?

Or would I have to write my own binding for this?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
<select data-bind="foreach: Dog, value: SelectedDogID">
    <option data-bind="text: DogName, value : DogID, attr: {title : DogID == $parent.SelectedDogID()'}" />
</select>
```

Although I agree that a custom binding would provide the cleanest solution.